# Copy Cells using IF for non -blank values

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a table where there are 3 columns which have blanks in them . 
I want to copy the non blank values to suppose D2. Say I have blank in C2 , B2 is not blank , then the value to be copied is B2 . If both C2 and B2 are blank , then value to be copied is A2. I am using the following formula:

```
=IF(C2="",B2,IF(B2="",A2, C2))
```

It is running correctly for the values where C2/B2 values are blank . But it throws up a 00-01-1900 Value in D2 when both the C2 and B2 cells are blank and I want only A2 data in the cell . Is there some way to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=IF(C2<>"",C2,IF(B2<>"",B2,IF(A2<>"",A2,"")))
```

(I assume your order of priority is C>B>A>Blank return

Comment: Great, if someone provides an accepted answer then please click the ^ arrow next to it to signify that it has worked and is a suitable solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it correctly:
D display the value of A / B / C in this order of priority.

Step 1:
`D` take the value of `B` if `C` is null.

```
=IF(C2="",B2,C2)
```

Step 2: If `B` is null then return `A`

```
=IF(B2="",A2,B2)
```

Result:

```
=IF(C2="",IF(B2="",A2,B2),C2)
```

In your code:

If `C` is null, We take `B`.
If `C` is not null:

- If `B` is null, We take `A`. *But it should have been `C` cause it's not null*
- If `B` is not null, Take `B`.